# make radio button clickable only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Argh! I cannot get this right. On a quiz I'm hosting, I'm trying to make it so only the radio button is clickable. Currently it is clickable on the radio button and/or text. How can I make it so only the radio is clickable?

I have a couple codes below that I really don't understand, I'll include them both though I'm sure they are not both necesssary but I don't know which one is to make it happen. Help is appreciated!

I cannot post the code without it preventing me saying it is not properly formatted or something so here are the links to the two files I'm using:

[slickQuiz.js](http://www.cdl-testing.net)

[slickQuiz-config.js](http://www.cdl-testing.net)

Comment: can you post a HTML portion that shows how your defining the radio buttons? Cheers

Comment: I wish I could but it's all written in the config.js file. And sorry about the link, it should work now.

Comment: Why in the world would you want only the radio button to be clickable? Being unable to choose an option/answer by clicking the actual text of that option/answer is a design flaw in many people's opinions. That is in fact one reason why `label`s were invented in HTML, so that options were clickable on either the radio buttons or the associated text. Beginner programmers are instructed in lessons like this http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jkm2/2.html to create clickable descriptions/options for radio buttons. Why would you want to move a decade backwards in usability?

Comment: Haha, I understand Mr. Myers, I do. But this is a specific case with a specific reason. In fact, I knew when I posted the question that someone would ask me why I'd want to. But I got my answer and that's what I came for. Take care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `slickQuiz.js` javascript, locate line number `129` and remove the `for` attribute on the label:

This line:

```
var optionLabel = '<label for="' + optionId + '">' + answer.option + '</label>';
```

Change to:

```
var optionLabel = '<label>' + answer.option + '</label>';
```

The `for` attribute on labels cause them to get associated with the `input` which is specified in the `for`. This will in turn allow the labels to be clicked in order to focus the associated `input`.

Answer (score 0):

do an `e.stopPropagation()` on text click ?

```
$('input[type='radio']').next().click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Edit - just checked your code - try removing 'for' in `'<label for="' + optionId + '">'`
This in essence means the click event for the text is binded to the corresponding radio button.
You can also use my code above to disable the click event for the text. I am using next() assuming the label is placed after the input element. MOdify it according to the placement.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what that means. Where would I put it?